# Nyquist Rate Determination

Tags: sampling, nyquist

If the Nyquist rate for xa (t) is Ωs, what is the Nyquist rate for xa(2t)?
Will it be the same, increase 2 folds or decrease 2 folds?

Comment: Try to figure out the Fourier transform of $x_a(2t)$ in terms of the Fourier transform of $x_a(t)$. This should give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is homework, so I'm not going to give you the answer, but will try to help you get there yourself.

With $xa(2t)$ everything happens twice as quickly (what was time $1$ with the original signal is time $2$ with the new signal, time $2$ becomes time $4$, etc.).  Given that everything is happening twice as fast as before, what would that do to the Nyquist frequency?